# Android copy file not working for local SQLite files

Tags: android, database, file-io

I'm using this piece of code to copy files from internal to external storage without losing any :

```java
public static void copyFile(String currentDBPath, String backupDBPath) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I try to copy images from internal storage or txt files it's working fine, without any errors and the new files are in sd card. But if I try to copy my local database files from `/data/data/package/databases/system.sqlite` it's creating a new file in the given destination, but the new database file is empty, without any tables or even data on it.

Any ideas why it's happening only with database files?

***Edit:***

As I noticed, the new database file which is copied is as big as the original one (145KB), but when I open it with sqlite browser there are no tables, no data...nothing.

Comment: Are you perhaps attempting the copy whilst the database is still open?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's closed while I'm trying to copy it to sd card.

Comment: With the exception of this: File currentDB = getContext().getDatabasePath(CurrentDBName); your code is identical to mine and mine works no problem.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure why it's not working properly,but if I use that code with image or txt file everything is ok. I have this issue only with sqlite files.

Comment: I get this behavior on my LG MyTouch, but not on a Galaxy tab.  The MyTouch copies part of the data, but not all, the Galaxy tab does fine.  I wonder if it's the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use:

```
            try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/com.our.package/databases/main.db";
                String backupDBPath = "main_" + additionalInfo + ".db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "File does not exist: " + currentDBPath);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "SDCard not writable, backup aborted.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error backing up database to sdcard.", ex);
            return getResources().getInteger(R.integer.unhandled_exception_from_api_service);
        }
```

We're able to back up the database to the sdcard and read it back using SQLite Browser.